# Apollo useMutation response best practice

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo and Shopify's Polaris components and I'm unsure of the best way to manage my response from a mutation.

I'm declaring my mutation in the following way.

```
const [updateShop, {error, data}] = useMutation(SHOP_SETTINGS_MUTATION);
```

And calling it within my component like this.

```
    const saveBar =
        showSaveBar ? (
            <ContextualSaveBar
                message="Unsaved changes"
                saveAction={{
                    onAction: () => {
                        updateShop({variables:{...shop, settings:settings}});
                    }
                }}
                discardAction={{
                    onAction: () => {
                        // do something here

                    }
                }}
            />) : (null);
```

However InteliJ is displaying the following warning:

> Promise returned from updateShop is ignored less... (⌘F1)
> Inspection info: Reports function calls that return a Promise that is not later used. These are usually unintended and indicate an error

**Am I doing something wrong here?**

[image showing InteliJ is suggesting my code is bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jLPc.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `updateShop` function returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which will return the results of your mutation. The warning is simply telling you that it is ignored. Normally you would do something like this ...

```
                    onAction: () => {
                        updateShop({variables:{...shop, settings:settings}})
                            .then((res) => { 
                               ...check the result object here to ensure
                               the operation succeeded...
                            });
                    }
```

See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#result

Comment: Thanks @Jason. But isn't this irrelevant given I'm handling the response in my declaration using:

`const [updateShop, {error, data}] = useMutation(SHOP_SETTINGS_MUTATION);` with `{error, data}` ?

Comment: True enough, but I just wanted to point out the reason for the warning. Additionally, you have a values defined for the data and the error, but have no notification when the operation is completed. For a long running process, you may want to disable the user input and re-enable it when it's complete. Using your method here, you would probably want to use a `useEffect` hook with the data and error values as dependencies.